# Why is the signature different for these two functions?

Tags: f#

What is the difference between these two functions?

```
let increment1 x = x +1 // (int -> 'a) -> 'a // why??
let increment2 x = x + 1 // int -> int // this is clear
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lack of space between `+` and `1` changes the meaning. When there is a space, it reads as operator `+` applied to argument `1`, but without a space it means "positive one", similarly to how `-1` means "negative one".

And since `+1` is a number of type `int`, then `x +1` must be a function application, applying function `x` to the argument `+1`, and therefore `x` must be of type `int -> 'a` for some generic type `'a`